# Python POST request same JS/PHP

Tags: javascript, php, python, http-post

I'm not good in js/php, but i need to convert code below to Python.

Javascript version:

```
function api_query(key,keyId,url,post,body,signature,cb){var method='POST';
    var date=new Date();
    var content_type='application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8;';
    var body_md5=CryptoJS.MD5(body);
    var http= new XMLHttpRequest();http.onreadystatechange=function(){if (http.readyState===4){cb(JSON.parse(http.responseText));}};
    http.open("POST",'http://'+url,true);http.setRequestHeader('x-pbx-date',date);
    http.setRequestHeader('Accept','application/json');
    http.setRequestHeader('Content-Type',content_type);
    http.setRequestHeader('Content-MD5',body_md5);
    http.setRequestHeader('x-pbx-authentication',keyId+':'+signature);
    http.send(body);}
```

PHP version:

```
    $post = http_build_query($post);
    $content_type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
    $content_md5 = hash('md5', $post);
    $signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $method."\n".$content_md5."\n".$content_type."\n".$date."\n".$url."\n", $secret_key, false));
    $headers = array('Date: '.$date, 'Accept: application/json', 'Content-Type: '.$content_type, 'x-pbx-authentication: '.$key_id.':'.$signature, 'Content-MD5: '.$content_md5);

    if (isset($opt['secure']) && $opt['secure']){
        $proto = 'https';
    }else{
        $proto = 'http';
    }
    $ch = curl_init($proto.'://'.$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    $res = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
    if ($res){return $res;}else{return false;}
```

I'v tried requests library:

```
headers = {
    'x-pbx-date': date,
    'Content-Type': content_type,
    'Content-MD5': body_md5_str,
    'x-pbx-authentication': signature,
}
payload = {
    'date_from': date_from,
    'date_to': date_to,
}
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
```

httlib2:

```
http = httplib2.Http()
response, content = http.request(url, 'POST', headers=headers, body=urllib.urlencode(payload))
```

urllib2:

```
req = urllib2.Request(url, data=urllib.urlencode(payload), headers=headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
```

Nothing works. In each try server response: not authenticated. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I guess your issue is authentication. You didn't show how you do that in Python, but I suppose there's something about that, since you somehow calculate `body_md5_str` and `signature` before you even have a body (`json.dumps` call), so there must be something wrong about it. Did you ensure your code generates the same values as JS and PHP code?

Personally, I would implement an authentication class, that would add necessary headers before request fires. Refer to [requests documentation on custom auth](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/authentication/#new-forms-of-authentication) for details, and here's my (untested) attempt at it, if I got the details right:

```
import requests
import hashlib
import hmac
import base64
from wsgiref.handlers import format_date_time
import datetime
from time import mktime

CONTENT_TYPE_FORM_URLENCODED = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

class OnlinePBXAuth(requests.auth.AuthBase):
    def __init__(self, key_id, secret):
        self.key_id = key_id
        self.secret = secret

    def __call__(self, r):
        content_type = r.headers.get("Content-Type", CONTENT_TYPE_FORM_URLENCODED)
        body = r.body or ""
        body_md5 = hashlib.md5(body).hexdigest()
        date = format_date_time(mktime(datetime.datetime.now().timetuple()))
        date = r.headers.get("Date", date)
        r.headers["Date"] = date
        r.headers["X-PBX-Date"] = date
        sign = "\n".join([r.method, body_md5, content_type, date, r.url, ""])
        signature = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(self.secret, sign, hashlib.sha1).hexdigest())
        r.headers["Content-MD5"] = body_md5
        r.headers["X-PBX-Authentication"] = "{0}:{1}".format(self.key_id, signature)
        return r
```

Not the prettiest code, but I guess that should do the trick.

Then, use it like this:

```
auth = OnlinePBXAuth(KEY_ID, KEY_SECRET)
...
data = {"date_from": date_from, "date_to": date_to}
r = requests.post(url, data, auth=auth)
...
```

Or maybe even like this:

```
session = requests.Session(auth=OnlinePBXAuth(KEY_ID, KEY_SECRET))
...
r1 = session.post(url, data)
...
r2 = session.post(another_url, another_data)
```

I'm not sure it would work with empty-bodied requests (like most GETs are) and multipart chunked bodies though (so figure on your own or just try to avoid those), but I suppose it should be fine for application/x-www-form-urlencoded and application/json encoded data.

Comment: Yes, I'm absolutely ensure my code generates same values as php/js ceteris paribus. I found it via Chrome step-by-step debugging. Same md5 hash and signature. Your code returns: `{"status":0,"comment":"not authenticated","data":""}` 
[Api examples and php/js library links in Russian](http://api.onlinepbx.ru/)

Comment: Hmm... Guess I'm wrong, then. Sorry. Unfortunately, I fail to see anything wrong with the code, then. Well, there's a service [RequestBin](http://requestb.in/) that displays HTTP requests that were made to it. Maybe it's worth try pointing both PHP and Python programs (with fixed dates, so requests would be completely the same) there and comparing requests with the same data? Maybe it would give some clues what could be wrong with Python version.

Comment: Ogh, there was once '\n' symbol in signature_str generated in my code. All methods including your work. Ty for help.